# Does ZFS check integrity by swap too?

Tags: swap, zfs

I have ECC memory and I'd like to put swap on a filesystem, which does integrity checks. Will ZFS check integrity by reading the swap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the swap space is a ZVOL or a swapfile on a ZFS dataset then it will benefit from all of ZFS' features, just as any other file or ZVOL would.

If the swap space is a bare partition or a swapfile on another filesystem, then it won't.

Comment: I read in the btrfs faq that btrfs does not support swap files and swap partitions. Is there something special about them which zfs managed to solve, but btrfs didn't?

Comment: dunno about "something special", but zfs devs wrote their code to make sure that swap works on zfs (BTW, early versions of zfsonlinux were prone to crashing if used for swap. works perfectly now).  btrfs devs didn't.